# What is the best way to isolate power hold-up circuit?

Tags: power, switches, diodes

I an currently designing a hold up circuit for a computer and I need to keep this load isolated from other circuits that don't need to worry about a brief loss of power. The research I've done has lead me to a circuit like this with Load 2 being the circuitry I need to hold up for the power interrupt. (D1 D2 part numbers are not correct, I just couldn't figure out how to get rid of them)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feiq6X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I need to hold this load up for 50ms. I'm short on space for this capacitor so the the forward voltage of these diodes is going to be significant factor. I have looked into Schottky diodes and for the current I expect to see for this load the forward voltage is ~0.5V. I have also looked at TI's SM74611 Smart Bypass Diode, which looks to be a power FET with some control on top of that, which has a forward voltage of 26mV. This would be awesome but the reverse voltage is 28V and I need a reverse voltage of at least 56V (derating specs).

What components would you recommend using for D1, D2 in this situation? Is Schottky the best way to go?

Comment: http://www.ti.com/document-viewer/LM76202-Q1/datasheet/recommended-operating-conditions-a-1429270218-roc#a_1429270218_ROC  LM76202-Q1 60-V, 2-A Integrated ideal diode with overvoltage and overcurrent protection

Comment: In the schematic editor, double-click or right-click on a component to set its properties.

Comment: If the diode drop is significant what about dV = 0.05s*0.64A/C if dV=0.32V, C=0.1F !! With an ESR of 50mohm,! You might need a small battery

Comment: I should have been clearer about the load, the circuits that need to be held up are good until 10V, so working dV is 18V... Which is still a giant cap, but...